# Can any brand or type of olive oil be used to light Chanukah candles?

Tags: chanuka, menora-chanukia, oil

Many of the stores in my neighborhood sell specially marked bottles or cans of olive oil for Chanukah.

A while ago, someone told me that I cannot use any store brand of olive oil (like Trader Joe's, Berio, etc.) I can only use the special "Chanukah" olive oil.

Offhand, I think that person is mistaken, but, I hope someone can provide a definitive source in either direction and answer:

1. Does olive oil have to be made *leshem mitzvah* - specifically for the purpose of being used for lighting Chanukah candles? Or can one use any olive oil brand?
2. The OU site states that all extra virgin olive oil is kosher even without a certification. Does the olive oil used for lighting need to be kosher? I.e., non-extra-virgin oil would need a certification if you were eating it.
3. Related to the previous question, if the oil needs to be certified, does one specifically need to use extra virgin, or can he use any grade?
4. May one use olive oil that had previously been used for eating such as oil left-over from a salad mixture? The oil may have spices in it as well. Does the oil for lighting need to be "clean"?

**NOTE** Please address only the oil issue. I know that there are numerous other kindling options.

Comment: You don't even need to use oil. You can use wax candles. The Rama says the custom is to use wax candles because their light is bright and clear. If so it seems unlikely there'd be that many rules regarding the grade of the olive oil.

Comment: They're all kosher; but I think edible olive oil doesn't stay lit so well(it flickers and has a smell).

Comment: @chachamNisan The "jelled" oil, and pretty much all olive oil smells pretty much alike. The flickering is not that much dependent on the oil. It's based mainly on surrounding air flow. I've used "standard" olive oil and it seems to have done the same job as the gelled Chanukah oil. It's juts more time-consuming and messier to set it up using floating wicks.

Comment: So what's the difference between regular olive oil and the one for lighting?

Comment: @chachamNisan That's the basis of my question. I don't believe that there is any! Perhaps the gelled ones are processed with some additive. Maybe its a combo of oils? I may ask that as a separate question. Edible olive oil remains liquid at room temperature.

Comment: I wonder what brand of olive oil they used in the Temple, and who certified it.

Comment: @Oliver Your user name is on the bottle ;-)

Comment: @Oliver: According to the Yalqut Re'uveini, the small jug of oil found before Chanukah was one of the small jugs Yaaqov returned across the river to retreive, leading to that battle with the angel. It was filled with oil by Shemu'el, and was used to annoint Sha'ul, David and Shelomo. The jug was inherited by Elisha, who used it to fill all the utensils in the Shunamit's home. Then it was stored in the Temple, alongside the jar of manna, Moshe's staff, Aaron's olive branch, and other miracle items. Which is why this one jug was not defiled when the Romans ransacked the menorah's oil supply.

Comment: Lesson I would learn from this medrash: The talmud says that Yaaqov returned for the oil because the righteous earn their money honestly, and honestly earned money is holy and precious. Yaaqov's honest relationship with money was an important lesson Shemu'el wanted to impress on our first kings. And it is apparently a blessing that money earned honestly will be enough to support the poor widow, and to provide light in times of darkness.

Answer (score 1):

1. As the oil is not the object of the Mitzvah (only the light is), it does not have to be made intentionally for Chanukkah and neither the olive tree must be planted to produce the Channukah oil only.
2. It is a Hidur to use an oil that's edible and therefore Kosher. That means not only 100% oil but also Land related Mitzvos etc.
3. The finer is the flame, the odor, the longer it lasts - the better Hidur is the oil.
4. It should not be used דרך בזיון - using for salad and pouring the left-overs into Chanukkiyah, but the other way around - buy it for Channukah and use the left-overs for a salad. But once again it is not מעכב.

**Clarification (thnx DoubleA)**: All the oil that is left in the bottle can be used for salads as it was not dedicated for Channuka Mitzvah, but the oil left in the cups after the burning retains its Keddushah and must be used preferably for another Mitzvah.

Comment: It's forbidden to use Chanukkah leftovers for salad.

Comment: It depends on how you מקדיש it all.

Comment: @DoubleAA The left-over oil retains *kedusha*? If so, does it need to be disposed in a specific way?

Comment: @danf yes burning

Comment: The flame should be clear.  To that end Rav Eliyashiv rules that there is a big hiddur (the best possible way) to use olive oil that is edible and is extra virgin.  Other grades of oil are not necessarily kosher and might involve some serious issues - especially using treif wax or ingredients in the process, thus rendering the oil treif.  I would say that it is better to use wax candles than treif oil. (see MB 673 s.k. 2, shaarei teshuva s.k. 1, Iggros Moshe chlk 1, 191)